# Web service calling another webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, async-await, httpclient

So I have a database that fills up when a value is not found inside of it already, basically is a web API written in C# that checks if there is a value inside of it, if its null then calls another web service that will retrieve the data and insert a new record into the database and return the newly created record to the user. The code is like this:

```
[HttpGet ("{idDocument}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPerson (string idDocument)
{
    // Get the person record from the database
    var person = await repository.GetPersonAsync (idDocument);

    // if the record does not exist, return not found
    if (person == null)
    {
        Person newPerson = await GetNewPersonFromRemoteServer(idDocument);
        var result = mapper.Map<Person, PersonResource>(newPerson);

        return Ok(result);
    }

    // Map the record to a resource to return to user
    var resource = mapper.Map<Person, PersonResource> (person);

    // return record resource to user
    return Ok (resource);
}


private async Task<Person> GetNewPersonFromRemoteServer(string id)
{
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    string address = "http://remoteservice.serv/?id=";
    string fullAddress = address + id;

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(fullAddress));
            string responseMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Person newPerson = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(responseMessage);

                repository.AddPersonAsync(newPerson);
                await uow.CompleteAsync();

                return newPerson;
            }

            return newPerson;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return newPerson;
    }
}
```

But the service is working sometimes and sometimes its returning null even tho if I execute the remote service I get a response with the correct data. I believe it has something to do with the nested async/await methods/functions but I cant seem to figure it out a better solution to my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are `AddPersonAsync` and `CompleteAsync` actually async? Because you do not await them.

Comment: the complete async is awaited, the addPersonasync was async but i turned it synchro to test it, but it seems its not the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have extremely faulty exception handling. Right now you swallow Exceptions. Moreover, you do it with Fatal Exceptions. That is a deadly sin of exception handling and can easily explain any odd behavior.

After a fatal exception your programm should always close. Ignoring them only leads to more followup errors that are impossible to debug or even predict.

You should read up on proper exception handling. Here are two articles I linked often:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET